# PHPUnit test case for controller symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am new in phpunit, I want to write test cases for controller action like
add/edit/delete , how can I start write test methods for these actions.

I can able to add test case like $this->assertGreaterThan(), I want to write assert on Entity or Repository to check method where record add or edit

Comment: Actually writing test to entitiy or repositrory is wrong, because it sound like you want testing not your functionality but database and fetching data from database. Someetimes maybe its really needed but I always trying to avoid it. Better concentrate on testing your services and apply some fynctionality test for contrellers like docs descibes it.

Comment: @excluded_once can you please share any link or any code to I could start write test case for controller for symfony2

Comment: please consider reading the docs of symfony2 - you where given a few hints including my link to the functional tests documentation, a pure code-example won't help you in any way.

Comment: @vipinsharma, actually doc descibes quite good all what you need to do. but if you really need some examples, please take a look to these dummy bundles:
https://github.com/Sleepness/UberTranslationAdminBundle/tree/develop/Tests
https://github.com/Sleepness/UberTranslationBundle/tree/redis/Tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with reading the documentation-chapter of symfony2: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests

Comment: above example cover assertions on web page like $this->assertGreaterThan(), I want to write assert on Entity or Repository

Comment: @vipinsharma that's not the same thing as testing the controllers, please edit your question if needed.